# Reliable Dictionary of Reliable Dictionaries

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, reliable-dictionary

Can I have a reliable dictionary which holds another reliable dictionary as its value?

```
var dicts = await StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, IReliableDictionary<string, string>>>("Dictionaries");
```

My first try gave a serialization error:

> Type
> 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Collections.DistributedDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'
> cannot be serialized.
> Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute,
> and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.
> If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.
> See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Comment: What is the goal of using a reliable dictionary inside a reliadble dictionary ? The "root" dictionary will make sure all items that are in the reliable dictionary are peristed as configured. That being said. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not supported by the `DataContractSerializer` You could however use `IReliableDictionary<string,IEnumerable<TValue>>`

Comment: The idea is to have a better key-management by segregating certain categories thru dictionaries.

Comment: @Sammy you could consider creating a composite key from both values and use that with a single reliable dictionary.

Comment: If you have a limited number of static categories, you might also just consider having multiple ReliableDictionary states that you operate against instead of making a dictionary of dictionaries.